# How to make ListView expand in a SplitPane?

Tags: xml, javafx, scenebuilder

I'm creating a scene with **JavaFX** and **SceneBuilder**. In one of the tabs there's a SplitPane that behaves not as I would like when I put the window in maximum size and drag it up to expand the latter view. **I would like the ListView to expand accordingly**, but once it reaches a maximum height it stops. How to fix this issue?

Here's a screenshot: as you can see **there's a big space between the listview and the splitpane separator**.

[image: Here's a screenshot.]

Here's the code of the xml:

```
   <TabPane prefHeight = "400.0"
         prefWidth = "600.0"
         tabClosingPolicy = "UNAVAILABLE"
         AnchorPane.bottomAnchor = "0.0"
         AnchorPane.leftAnchor = "0.0"
         AnchorPane.rightAnchor = "0.0"
         AnchorPane.topAnchor = "28.0">
    <tabs>
        <Tab text = "Clump">
            <content>
                <SplitPane dividerPositions = "0.22713864306784662"
                           orientation = "VERTICAL">
                    <items>
                        <VBox alignment = "CENTER_LEFT"
                              spacing = "10.0">
                            <padding>
                                <Insets bottom = "10.0"
                                        left = "10.0"
                                        right = "10.0"
                                        top = "10.0" />
                            </padding>
                            <children>
                                <HBox alignment = "CENTER_LEFT"
                                      prefHeight = "100.0"
                                      prefWidth = "200.0"
                                      spacing = "10.0">
                                    <children>
                                        <RadioButton fx:id = "radioClump"
                                                     mnemonicParsing = "false"
                                                     selected = "true"
                                                     text = "Ricerca per clump ID">
                                            <toggleGroup>
                                                <ToggleGroup fx:id = "clumpSearch" />
                                            </toggleGroup>
                                        </RadioButton>
                                        <TextField fx:id = "textClumpId"
                                                   promptText = "Clump id" />
                                        <Button fx:id = "searchClumpButton"
                                                mnemonicParsing = "false"
                                                text = "Cerca" />
                                    </children>
                                </HBox>
                                <RadioButton fx:id = "radioStar"
                                             mnemonicParsing = "false"
                                             text = "Clump che possono ospitare una stella massiccia"
                                             toggleGroup = "$clumpSearch" />
                            </children>
                        </VBox>
                        <VBox alignment = "BOTTOM_CENTER"
                              prefHeight = "100.0"
                              prefWidth = "200.0">
                            <children>
                                <ListView>
                                    <padding>
                                        <Insets bottom = "15.0"
                                                left = "15.0"
                                                right = "15.0"
                                                top = "15.0" />
                                    </padding>
                                </ListView>
                                <HBox alignment = "BOTTOM_RIGHT"
                                      prefWidth = "600.0"
                                      spacing = "5.0">
                                    <children>
                                        <Button mnemonicParsing = "false"
                                                text = "&lt;" />
                                        <Button mnemonicParsing = "false"
                                                text = "&gt;" />
                                    </children>
                                    <padding>
                                        <Insets top = "5.0" />
                                    </padding>
                                </HBox>
                            </children>
                        </VBox>
                    </items>
                </SplitPane>
            </content>
        </Tab>
      [... OTHER TABS ...]
    </tabs>
</TabPane>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `VBox` will size its child nodes according to their `preferredHeight` unless otherwise directed. You can override this behavior by setting the static `VBox` property [`vgrow`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/VBox.html#setVgrow-javafx.scene.Node-javafx.scene.layout.Priority-) on a node. In FXML, the syntax is:

```xml
<ListView VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
    <padding>
        <Insets bottom = "15.0"
                left = "15.0"
                right = "15.0"
                top = "15.0" />
    </padding>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I needed!